Работа с сабмодулями в git
Сижу через IDEA в проекте, где есть сабмодули.
Так вот, иногда есть потребность переключиться на другую версию того или иного сабмодуля.
Но почему-то, я  не могу выбирать ветки, пока не пропишу следующие команды:
git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
git fetch origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

До их прописывания, в новом проекте, я в списке вижу только master.
При этом сделать checkout на нужную ветку тоже не получается.
Почему так происходит?
Может я неправильно юзаю IDE и можно работать нормально с сабмодулями без этих команд?

"я не могу выбирать ветки, пока не пропишу следующие команды" - ¿А выбирать было из чего? ¿В локальный репозиторий до прописывания этих команд были выкачены коммиты, не относившиеся к выбранной в родительском репозитории ветке сабмодуля?

Вот да тоже про это подумал, не были ли они до авлены с --depth 1

@user7860670 Т.е я должен был выкачить репу сабмодуля отдельно и после этого я бы смог свободно выбрать нужную мне ветку? Т.е не правиль делать fetch в папке сабмодуля, которая находит в родительском проекте?

Суть в том, что выбирать можно только из того, что уже было выкачено. Выкачено отдельным репозиторием или в качестве сабмодуля - не важно. Ну и да, для сабмодулей обычно выкачивается только единственная ветка или даже единственный коммит - поэтому выбирать было не из чего.

@user7860670 а что делает каждая команда из вопроса? Просто нашел их где-то и стал повсеместно юзать.

Эти команды выкачивают все ветки.
